# docker-compose up not adding code to remote container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've run through the initial [Overview of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) exactly as written and it works just fine locally with boot2docker. However, if I try to do a `docker-compose up` on a remote host, it does not add the code to the remote container.

To reproduce:

1. Run through the initial [Overview of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) exactly as written.
2. Install [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) and start a Dockerized VM on any cloud provider.

   1. `docker-machine create --driver my-favourite-cloud composetest`
   2. `eval "$(docker-machine env composetest)"`
3. Now that you're working with a remote host, run `docker-compose up` on the original code.

   1. `composetest $ docker-compose up`

Redis runs fine but the Flask app does not.

```
composetest $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
794c90928b97        composetest_web     "/bin/sh -c 'python    About a minute ago   Exited (2) About a minute ago                       composetest_web_1
2c70bd687dfc        redis               "/entrypoint.sh redi   About a minute ago   Up About a minute               6379/tcp            composetest_redis_1
```

What went wrong?

```
composetest $ docker logs 794c90928b97
python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can we confirm it?

```
composetest $ docker-compose run -d  web sleep 60
Starting composetest_redis_1...
composetest_web_run_3

composetest $ docker exec -it a4 /bin/bash
root@a4a73c6dd159:/code# ls -a
.  ..
```

Nothing there. Can we fix it?

Comment out volumes in `docker-compose.yml`

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  # volumes:
  #  - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  image: redis
```

Then just `docker-compose up` and it works!

Let's try again on boot2docker.

```
composetest $ eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
composetest $ docker-compose up
Recreating composetest_redis_1...
Recreating composetest_web_1...
Attaching to composetest_redis_1, composetest_web_1
...
```

The Flask app does work but it has a serious problem. If you change app.py, the Flask dev server doesn't reload and those changes aren't automatically seen. Even if you stop the container and `docker-compose up` again, the changes still aren't seen. I realize we lose this **essential** feature because the volume is no longer mounted. But not mounting the volume is the only way I've been able to get docker-compose to work with a remote host. We should be able to get both local and remote hosts to work using the same `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`.

How do I develop interactively with a local VM and deploy to a remote VM without having to change the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml?

Versions:

- Docker 1.7.0
- Docker Compose 1.3.0
- Docker Machine 0.3.0

Comment: ``docker-compose`` has nothing to do with "adding code to the host".

Comment: Goog point. What I really meant is that the code isn't getting into the container (hence there's nothing to run). I updated the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm really looking for is found in this [Using Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) doc. By [Extending services in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) you're able to develop interactively with a local VM and deploy to a remote VM without having to change the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 5):

Compose just does pretty much the same thing as you can do with the regular command line interface under the hood. So your command is roughly equivalent to:

```
$ docker run --name web -p 5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/code --link redis:redis web
```

The issue is that the volume is relative to the docker host, not the client. So it will mount the working directory on the remote VM, not the client. In your case, this directory is empty.

If you want to develop interactively with a remote VM, you will have to check out the source and edit the files on the VM.

UPDATE: It seems that you actually want to develop and test locally, then deploy a production version to a remote VM. (Apologies if I still misunderstand). To do this, I suggest you have a separate Compose file for development where you mount the local volume, then rebuild and deploy the image for production. By rebuilding the image, it will pick up the latest version of the code. Mounting a volume in production breaks because you've hidden the code in the image with an empty directory.

It's also worth pointing out that Docker don't advise using Compose in production currently.

Comment: I do **not** want to develop interactively with a remote VM. I want to develop interactively with a local VM and deploy to a remote VM without having to change the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml. That's a much better way to frame this question, I'll update it.

Comment: Also note the Dockerfile from the overview https://docs.docker.com/compose/#create-a-docker-image has an `ADD`. I would expect that to put the code into the VM regardless of the `-volumes` in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: s/VM/container/ in the comment immediately above :(

Comment: Yeah, that's a different question, which has covered here before. Developing locally then deploying remotely is the normal way of working with Docker. You'll just need to use a different compose file for the production version. I'll try to explain.

Comment: You've got the intent of my question right. And this is the answer I feared I'd get. Maintaining 2 docker-compose.yml files isn't optimal and really seems to me like it just shouldn't be necessary. Can I ask where this has been covered before, specifically with respect to docker compose? Do you have a link?

Comment: No, I meant a lot of people have asked the dev to production question on SO. But not specifically the Compose question. I'm not really sure why you feel you should only have one compose file; IMO they are very strongly tied to their environment (volumes, links, ports are all likely to change between environments).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this *"can't open file 'app.py'"* problem following the Getting Started tutorials, for me it was because I'm running Docker in Windows. I needed to make sure that I'd shared the drive containing my project directory in Docker settings.

Source: see [the "Shared Drive" section of Docker Settings in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#docker-settings)